# css jquery changing class style

Tags: jquery, css, class

```
$("#menu li").click(function () {
        $("#menu .active").removeAttr("class");
        $(this).attr("class","active");
    });

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="m1" class="active"><a>link 1</a></li>
                <li id="m2"><a>link 1</a></li>
                <li id="m3"><a>link 2</a></li>
                <li id="m4"><a>link 3</a></li>
                <li id="m5"><a>link 4</a></li>
                <li id="m6"><a>link 5</a></li>
                <li id="m6"><a href="">link 6</a></li>
                <li id="m7"><a href="">link 7</a></li>
                <li id="m8"><a>link 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#menu .active{
    background:white;
}

#menu .active a{
    opacity:0.5;
}

#menu a{
    color:#08042b;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #6055c8;
    position:relative;

}
```

When i click a link the first time everything seems to be ok..
When i click for second time background-color of this li changed li font takes opacity 0.5,
previous li hasn't active className but previous li text hasn't go to opacity:1
Any help?

Comment: instead of using ```attr``` for adding and removing classes user [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: i try this..
basic,you have right in this point.
but don't change something

Comment: $("#menu li").click(function () {
  $("#menu .active").removeAttr("class").find("a").css("opacity",1);
  $(this).addClass("active");
 });

That's works but why my original code doesn't work?

Comment: If you insist on such bad practice, use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: @user726730: the reason jquery legends created ```.class``` was to make developers' life easier. I wonder why would you take a round path?

Answer (score 2):

As it was said, using `$("#menu .active").removeClass("active");` is more correct than removing the entire class attribute was you did, as you may ending losing other classes you may have, thus resulting in unexpected behavior.

Comment: why this:  $("#menu .active").removeClass("active").find("a").css("opacity",1); works but this:  $("#menu .active").removeClass("active"); not??
The class change in any case but only opacity change in the first code